# many errors if include STL: string

Tags: c++, stl, visual-studio-2013

In new studio(Visual Studio 2013 ultimate Trial) there were many errors!

Code without errors:

```
//#include <cstring> // error yhals.h:666,667

//#include <string> // error yhals.h , xrefwrap , type_traits

int main()
{

    return 0;
}
```

If I include "cstring" or "string", there are many errors:

Include cstring : (only 4 errors yhals.h:666,667)

> http://s7.postimg.org/y511l51tn/errorcstring.png

Include string :

> http://pastebin.com/M0PdZC6G

how to fix it?

Comment: And where is defined MessageBox, MB_OK etc. ?

Comment: I tried reinstalling the studio, and more, nothing helped.
(need to compile code for WinXP, I chose for this "Visual Studio 2013 - Windows XP (v120_xp)" toolset)

Comment: Martin Perry, now I corrected the post.

Comment: `WinUser.h` -- `#ifdef UNICODE
#define MessageBox  MessageBoxW
#else
#define MessageBox  MessageBoxA
#endif // !UNICODE`   There is it defined.